# Hide a div after user selects one option

Tags: mobile, drop-down-menu, show-hide

i did not found the answer i was looking for, so that why i'm creating this question. I have a div that shows another one on click but i need to hide it (the div that appears on click) after the user selects one of the options, how can i do that?

When user's click on "#showmenu" the div ".mob" appears, after clicking in one of the ".mob" li's the ".mob" div dissapears.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="showmenu"><img src="images/mobile.png" /></div>
<div class="mob" style="display: none;">
   <ul>
      <a data-scroll href="#home"><li>INÍCIO</li></a>
      <a data-scroll href="#servicos"><li>EU FAÇO</li></a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.mob').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont have any idea of the bootstrap or jquery plugins you are using but based on what is given, i'd say this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.mob').slideToggle("fast");
            $('.mob a').click(function () {
                 $('.mob').slideToggle("fast");
             });
    });
});
```

Point to note there is a performance issue here , i.e code could be optimized better to search for classes or elements within a specific div than the whole document

Comment: Not sure if that would work with the $('.mob a').click inside the $('#showmenu').click.
Fairly certain it works if $('.mob a').click  is bound outside of it.  I can post if you're not sure what I mean (or if I'm wrong and it works as is).  Better than my suggestion of giving the <li>s ids or a class, but you're right: on a big site better to not have 'a' be the rightmost on a pattern.

Comment: Doesn't really matter adds up to the same effect if outside or inside, being outside would mean an event would be attached to the elements click even when document is ready , if its inside the show menu click event the function would be attached once the showmenu is clicked or each time it is clicked.

Comment: Nice.  Defers the binding.  I wouldn't have thought of that.  
I think I'd still keep it outside because I'd be looking all over the place for it and I'd never notice it indented and inside another function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Should those really be `<a>` if you don't intend to go anywhere?  Can they just be `<li>`?

After that I think you want to give id's to the `<li>` that you have and then create a function much like the one you did for `$('showmenu').click...` that would hide the .mob.

Or if the `<li>` all get treated the same, maybe give them all the same class and just have one function for the class.

Comment: The li's take the user to other parts of the same page (it's a one page website). I don't know how to create js codes, i found that one searching the web but then i noticed this problem (that the div didn't close after clicking the li's)

Comment: Thank's Mark, i tried what you said and worked perfectly. Here's the code:<br/>`$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                $('.mob').slideToggle("fast");
        });
  
  $('.close').click(function() {
                $('.mob').slideToggle();
        });
    });`

Comment: I assume you added the class 'close' to the <li>s or the <a>s.  You could also do as Dasith said and use $('.mob a') and not add the class 'close' to the <li>s or <a>s.

Comment: Yes, i added the class 'close' to the <li>s. Thanks for the help guys!